# Image Rendering problem

Tags: ipad

application is e-book reader, we are using svg format to render the pages ,the prob is while rendering the pages in ipad, images are getting rendered but they are taking  time to get render,can any one please tell me to solve this issue ?

thank in advance..

prasad

cvvprasad.dingari@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Rendering an image will always take time.  With an e-book reader you have the advantage of knowing by-in-large that page views will be sequential.  One idea is to render in the background while the user is viewing the previous page, and swapping which is on top when they change the page.